# Get the first 9 of an array that is backwards

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there an easier way to get the first 9 of an array that is backwards?

```
var backwards=['s','d','r','a','w','k','c','a','B','s','I','y','a','r','r','A','y','M'];

f=backwards.slice(0);
f=f.slice(0,9);//front
f.reverse();

console.log(f.join());    //returns 'B,a,c,k,w,a,r,d,s'
```

It's just plain confusing this way!

Comment: You could reverse and then get the last 9, but that's not much simpler.

Comment: Don't forget to declare `f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even more simple:

```
backwards.reverse().slice(-9);
```

```js
alert(['s','d','r','a','w','k','c','a','B','s','I','y','a','r','r','A','y','M'].reverse().slice(-9).join(''));
```

Comment: Note that this modifies the original array.

Comment: @FelixKling Good point. Maybe the `reverse` and `slice` can be reversed then to overcome that?

Comment: Or use `backwards.slice(0).reverse().slice(-9);` to prevent overwriting ;)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can do it in one statement:

```
backwards.slice(0,9).reverse().join()
```

Comment: Yeah, there's no reason at all for the first `slice` in the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

**Beware** reversing in the beginning will also change your original array

```
var words = backwards.reverse().slice(-9).join('');
console.log(backwards[0] === 's'); // false
```

where slicing first will create a new array and be leave the original intact

```
var words = backwards.slice(0,9).reverse().join()
console.log(backwards[0] === 's'); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is:

```
var backwards = ['s','d','r','a','w','k','c','a','B','s','I','y','a','r','r','A','y','M'];
var f = [];

for (var i=8; i>0; i--) {
    f.push(backward[i]);
}
// f = ['B', 'a', 'c', 'k', 'w', 'a', 'r', 'd', 's']
```